# Using Xcode 4.6.3 can't distribute my iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am using Xcode 4.6.3 and OS X lion (10.7.5). i created an iOS app and now i am publishing this app. i completed every thing, uploaded pictures and do different things on iTunes connect. At the end when i click "Submit for Review" it gives me error of "Submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later." and when i click button validate or distribute my app through Xcode archive i get following message.
"Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode." I don't know whether it is because i am using Xcode 4.6.3 version or something else. I can't upgrade my Xcode or OS X because my macbook of older version and other newer version of OS are incompatible with this macbook.

Kindly solve my problem how to distribute my app through this Xcode.

Comment: i can't upgrade my os or Xcode version as my macbook can't support. is there other way i can upload my app?

Comment: well, yea you can. but it doesn't sounds too easy https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Comment: application loader 3 is also not supported by my computer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will need access to a newer Mac so you can install an up to date version of OSX so you can install an up to date version of XCode.

Second hand Mac Minis are often the most economical choice if you can't borrow anything.